# MongoDB - Sorting a query twice?

Tags: mongodb

right now I am using this query to get my result and sorting it like this to make a highscore list. This works as planned with the query below.

However, I want to be able to sort them if there is two results with equal value.

If there are two results that have the value 5, I want to sort it by time. So I get the one with the highest score, and the one who registered the result first. I have mongoDB's 'createdAt' and 'updatedAt' that I want to use.

```
 User.find().sort({score: -1}).limit(10).exec(function(err, users) {

 });
```

Any pointers in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
User.find().sort({score: -1, updatedAt: 1}).limit(10).exec(function(err, users) {

});
```

This will sort by `score` descending, followed by `updatedAt` ascending. Mentioned [here.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/)